# Passing React values from child to parent

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, material-ui

I am struggling to work out something that is likely very simply. My parent component is a Search widget, which needs to use Filters defined in a separate Drawer component. Currently the user can type in a search query, which calls an API, and it needs to filter the results based on selectors form the drawer component. However, I cannot link the parent and child to make this happen!!

The parent component (which includes the '' component within):

```html
function SuburbSearch(props: Props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState<App.Suburb | null>(null);
    const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');
    ...
    
    return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="search"
      getOptionLabel={(option) => (typeof option === 'string' ? option : option.name + ' ' + option.state)}
      filterOptions={(x) => x}
      options={options}
      ...
      ...
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Search for a suburb"
          ...,
            startAdornment: (
              <InputAdornment position="start">
                <Filters></Filters>
              </InputAdornment>
            ),
            endAdornment: (
              <React.Fragment>
                {loading ? <CircularProgress color="inherit" size={20} /> : null}
                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
              </React.Fragment>
            ),
          }}
          fullWidth
        />
      )}
```

The child component (this is the 'Filter'):

```html
export default function Filters() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  const [dollar, setDollars] = useState<number[]>([0, 20000000]);
  const [type, setType] = React.useState<string | null>('all');
  
  ...
  const list = (anchor: Anchor) => (
    <div className={classes.root} 
      role="presentation" /*onClick={toggleDrawer(false)} onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(false)}/*/>
      <Grid className={classes.main} container spacing={2}>
        <Grid className={classes.row} item xs={1} md={2} />
        <Grid className={classes.row} item xs={10} md={8}>
          <Typography className={classes.header} align='center' gutterBottom>
            Property Type
          </Typography>
          <ToggleButtonGroup value={type} onChange={handleTypeChange} exclusive>
            <ToggleButton value="all" >All</ToggleButton>
            <ToggleButton value="some" >Some</ToggleButton>
          </ToggleButtonGroup>
        </Grid>
        ...
      </Grid>
   </div>
}
```

Comment: could you reproduce the problem in codesandbox?

Comment: Without knowing why and what data you need to send from child to parent, it's not possible give you any suggestion. Produce the sandbox or explicitly mention all data around there that interact between parent and child component and their direction of flow.

Comment: In recat js it's not possible to send data from child component to parent component. You can do that using redux and react- redux library.

Comment: I will try to reformat, but a bit tricky as there is a lot of code already with these components (which confuses thing even more).  The pattern I am looking for could actually be quite simple... In the above I have a "SuburbSearch", which is effectively just a Search input field that calls an API, and the results need to be filtered; The filters are in a separate Drawer component called "Filters"... But what I can't work out is how to read the Filter values in the SuburbSearch component when the filter component is closed...

Comment: Okay if you need something from a component regardless of the component is mounted in the DOM or not then put that data in context, and access it from it anywhere you need. If you know redux then you can also use it.

Comment: I would've though there was an easy way to get state feedback from child to parent without needing 'yet another library'?

Comment: You only need to send a state from child to parent to run some functionality on it? Then you don't need anything from context or redux.

Comment: Didn't you get the answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I'm providing you with some basic state management technique in Pure React, because so far I came to know by discussing with you in comment section.

### Pattern 1, straight forward

Let's say you have a Component, `comp1` namely, and it has some props including a method that requires some data from its direct *child component*, let's say `Comp2`:

```js
const Comp1 = ({ onActionOrChild }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Comp2 onAction={onActionOrChild} />
    </>
  )
}

const Comp2 = ({ onAction }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onAction}>
      ...
    </form>
  )
}
```

In short, here we have a component that requires some data, let's say some form data, from one of its descendants, so we passed it down to that children. But the **problem** here is ***Prop drilling***, `Comp1` needs to receive a prop that it never uses.

### Pattern 2, solving Prop Drilling with Context API

Now, react *Context API* is stable, which is very powerful to achieve something that used to require other state-management library.

> Version 16.3 introduces a new context API that is more efficient and
> supports both static type checking and deep updates. - [Docs](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html)

If we use context API, we can rip those methods out from the component and put them in a new file, that will create the context provider so that different component across the Application can communicate with each other, without passing down the props to the component a few level downs through the intermediate components that never use it.

Context.js

```js
export const AppContext = createContext();

export AppContextProvider = ({children}) => {

  const onAction = () => {}
  return (
    <AppContextProvider.Provider
      value={{onAction}}
    >
    {children}
    </AppContextProvider.Provider>
  )
  
}
```

Now, if we need a method in any piece of the Application we need to just hook up the *context API*:

```js
import { AppContext } from "./Context.js"

const comp3 = ({}) => {
  const { onAction } = useContext(AppContext);
  
  return (
    <form onSubmit={onAction}>
    ...
    </form>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can do it simply by passing a function as a prop, like this:

parent component

```
childCallback(value) {
    // value passed from child
}

return {
    <ChildComponent passToParent={this.childCallback}/>
}
```

child component

```
this.props.passToParent(childValue);
```